# Join n observable sources on key, with potentially missing keys

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have multiple data sources which share a tag/key which I need to re-synchronize. The type signature would look a bit like this:

```
IObservable<R> JoinOnKey<T,R>(IObservable<T>[] sources, 
                              Func<T,int> getKey, 
                              Func<T[],R> projection)
```

Unfortunately there are two complications:

1. some sources may have missing tags, but I still want to get the others

This implies that the function needs to 'give up' waiting after a certain time period. So the signature changes to this:

```
IObservable<R> JoinOnKey<T,R>(IObservable<T>[] sources, 
                              Func<T,int> getKey, 
                              Func<T[],R> projection,
                              int maxItemsToWaitBeforeGivingUp)
```

2. though tags arrive in the same (increasing) order on each source, there is an upstream 'reset' function which can set them all back to zero.

After researching Buffer, Join, GroupJoin, Zip etc., I've ended up hacking my own solution, which maintains an internal queue of arrays, which has to be locked on every new incoming item. I'm not happy with it, so I'm interested in any ideas or pointers to potentially 'cleaner' solutions.

Comment: 1. My initial thought is that this shouldn't be on you, but rather on the sender and that you just return a fail message to the sender instead of trying fix "their" problem, but I guess that's not really possible? 2. Could you post an example of what the handling of these "odd" items look like now?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall, I agree. Actually your comment did give me a rather cunning idea, which would be to 'fill' holes in each source independently, then do a simple Join. However that still doesn't cover the case where one source is not firing at all...

Answer (score 1):

You mention giving up after a certain time but your code has a parameter for giving up after a certain number of items.  I am going to assume the code is a typo.

I think this code satisfies your first constraint.  I am not 100% certain of your 2nd constraint.  Do you receive some notification of this reset event?  Without such a notification I'm not sure you can reliably handle it correctly.

```
var count = sources.Length;
var timer = Observable.Timer(maxTimeToWaitBeforeGivingUp);

sources
    .Merge()
    .GroupByUntil(getKey, g => g.Take(count).TakeUntil(timer).Count())
    .SelectMany(g => g.ToArray().Select(projection));
```

Comment: Well it wasn't a typo, but all things considered, I don't mind giving up after a given time. I'm going to have to think about your code and try it out to see if it does what I want. Thanks for the pointers.